# Look back 7 days from a specif date and retrieve a value only if the day exists

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, datetime

I have a table which represents the number of hours worked for a specific day. From that table I want to be able to add 7 more columns to each row that represent the hours worked on the previous 7 days.

I've been using LAG() to accomplish that and it was working fine until I found an issue where I had a gap between days and now instead of picking the previous 7 days I'm picking the 7 previous rows.

This script demonstrates what I'm trying to accomplish.

```
DECLARE @data TABLE ( 
    [user_id] int,
    [date] DATETIME, 
    [day_hours_worked] VARCHAR(15)
);

INSERT INTO @data
VALUES 
  ( '1', '2019-09-07 00:00:00.000', '07_8' )
, ( '1', '2019-09-08 00:00:00.000', '08_4' )
, ( '1', '2019-09-09 00:00:00.000', '09_6' )
, ( '1', '2019-09-10 00:00:00.000', '10_8' )
, ( '1', '2019-09-11 00:00:00.000', '11_4' )
, ( '1', '2019-09-12 00:00:00.000', '12_6' )
, ( '1', '2019-09-13 00:00:00.000', '13_8' )
, ( '1', '2019-09-14 00:00:00.000', '14_4' )
, ( '1', '2019-09-20 00:00:00.000', '20_8' );

select 
    [user_id],
    [date],
    [day_hours_worked],
    LAG([day_hours_worked], 1) OVER (PARTITION BY [user_id] ORDER BY  [date]) [Hours-1],
    LAG([day_hours_worked], 2) OVER (PARTITION BY [user_id] ORDER BY  [date]) [Hours-2],
    LAG([day_hours_worked], 3) OVER (PARTITION BY [user_id] ORDER BY  [date]) [Hours-3],
    LAG([day_hours_worked], 4) OVER (PARTITION BY [user_id] ORDER BY  [date]) [Hours-4],
    LAG([day_hours_worked], 5) OVER (PARTITION BY [user_id] ORDER BY  [date]) [Hours-5],
    LAG([day_hours_worked], 6) OVER (PARTITION BY [user_id] ORDER BY  [date]) [Hours-6],
    LAG([day_hours_worked], 7) OVER (PARTITION BY [user_id] ORDER BY  [date]) [Hours-7] 
from @data
```

This is what I get.

```
user_id date    day_hours_worked    Hours-1 Hours-2 Hours-3 Hours-4 Hours-5 Hours-6 Hours-7
1   2019-09-07 00:00:00.000 07_8    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
1   2019-09-08 00:00:00.000 08_4    07_8    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
1   2019-09-09 00:00:00.000 09_6    08_4    07_8    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
1   2019-09-10 00:00:00.000 10_8    09_6    08_4    07_8    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
1   2019-09-11 00:00:00.000 11_4    10_8    09_6    08_4    07_8    NULL    NULL    NULL
1   2019-09-12 00:00:00.000 12_6    11_4    10_8    09_6    08_4    07_8    NULL    NULL
1   2019-09-13 00:00:00.000 13_8    12_6    11_4    10_8    09_6    08_4    07_8    NULL
1   2019-09-14 00:00:00.000 14_4    13_8    12_6    11_4    10_8    09_6    08_4    07_8
1   2019-09-20 00:00:00.000 20_8    14_4    13_8    12_6    11_4    10_8    09_6    08_4
```

The last row is the only incorrect one because it's looking at the previous 7 rows instead of the previous 7 days. In my scenario the expected result should be:

```
user_id date    day_hours_worked    Hours-1 Hours-2 Hours-3 Hours-4 Hours-5 Hours-6 Hours-7
1   2019-09-07 00:00:00.000 07_8    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
1   2019-09-08 00:00:00.000 08_4    07_8    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
1   2019-09-09 00:00:00.000 09_6    08_4    07_8    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
1   2019-09-10 00:00:00.000 10_8    09_6    08_4    07_8    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
1   2019-09-11 00:00:00.000 11_4    10_8    09_6    08_4    07_8    NULL    NULL    NULL
1   2019-09-12 00:00:00.000 12_6    11_4    10_8    09_6    08_4    07_8    NULL    NULL
1   2019-09-13 00:00:00.000 13_8    12_6    11_4    10_8    09_6    08_4    07_8    NULL
1   2019-09-14 00:00:00.000 14_4    13_8    12_6    11_4    10_8    09_6    08_4    07_8
1   2019-09-20 00:00:00.000 20_8    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    14_4    13_8
```

Is this even possible using LAG()? Is there a better way to accomplish what I want?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: A more pertinent question is why do you need to do this in the first place?  What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Outer join onto a calendar table that is guaranteed to have one row per date then carry on using `LAG` as before

Comment: @iamdave I need to do this because I have access the previous 7 days hours worked in a single row per day. This is because I am using this data to feed a report which knows nothing about previous or next rows and needs it to do some calculations.

Comment: @MartinSmith Can you provide some code please?

Comment: No time but the concept is quite simple. Create a calendar table with a row per date for every date in the range of interest for the foreseeable future. Select on that with a where clause of the period of interest. This gives you a row per date, Now outer join onto your original table, you still have a row per date so you don't get the missing row issue and your `LAG` approach counting rows will still work

Comment: @MartinSmith Tried your solution but unfortunately only worked for a single user. Nevertheless thank you very much for your useful input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is an elegant way to do this in SQL Server.  The simplest may be a `case` expression:

```
(case when lag(date, 1) over (partition by user_id order by date) = dateadd(day, 1, date)
      then lag(day_hours_worked, 1) over (partition by [user_id] order by [date]) 
 end) as [Hours-1],
```

Some databases support `range` with time intervals, making this simpler.

EDIT:

You can do what you want using `apply`:

```
select d.*, d2.*, d2.*
from data d outer apply
     (select max(case when dd.diff = 1 then d2.day_hours_worked end) as w1,
             max(case when dd.diff = 2 then d2.day_hours_worked end) as w2,
             max(case when dd.diff = 3 then d2.day_hours_worked end) as w3,
             max(case when dd.diff = 4 then d2.day_hours_worked end) as w4,
             max(case when dd.diff = 5 then d2.day_hours_worked end) as w5,
             max(case when dd.diff = 6 then d2.day_hours_worked end) as w6,
             max(case when dd.diff = 7 then d2.day_hours_worked end) as w7
      from data d2 cross apply
           (values (datediff(day, d2.date, d.date) )) dd(diff)
      where d2.date < d.date and d2.date >= dateadd(day, -7, d.date)
     ) d2;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=dcf797cc14b4805c90920122b6f6ed0c) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: You meant dateadd(day, `-1`, date) right? Unfortunately I already tried the CASE approach but it still looks at the previous row. So in my scenario once I reach the -6 day (which is the 14th) the  `lag(date, 6)` is already looking at the previous 6th row which is 9th day.

Comment: this won't work as desired, If there is a single missing day out of 7 for the most recent day then the effect will cascade down and all the date conditions will evaluate to false and so all columns will be null instead of just the one for the missing day

Comment: @MartinSmith . . . You are right.  I included a working answer.

Comment: @GordonLinoff In my opinion this is uggly (don't like cross applys). It's like you said there is no elegant way of doing this in SQL. But it works perfectly!!!  Even for more than one user. Thank you very much!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Your logic looks correct and it only fails because of missing dates. So I thought if we add missing dates, your logic will work.

Please follow my code. You may need to change some parts of that but it gives you the result you want for one single user.

```
;with wrk as (
    select 
        [user_id],
        [date],
        [day_hours_worked]
    from @data
)
-- generate list of dates, starting from min date in your table
, allDates as (
    select Dt = dateadd(day, row_number() over (order by object_id) - 1, (select min([date]) from wrk))
    from sys.objects
)
-- select only dates missing from your table
, missingDates as (
    select Dt
    from allDates
    where Dt < (select max([date]) from wrk)
    and not exists (select [date] from wrk where wrk.[date] = Dt)
)
, fullData as (
    select [user_id],
            [date],
            [day_hours_worked]
    from wrk
    union
    -- we need [user_id] here, so I get it from your table
    -- this is not perfect and works only if you work on one single user
    select (select top 1 [user_id] from wrk), Dt, null
    from missingDates
)
, final as (
    select 
        [user_id],
        [date],
        [day_hours_worked],
        LAG([day_hours_worked], 1) OVER (PARTITION BY [user_id] ORDER BY  [date]) [Hours-1],
        LAG([day_hours_worked], 2) OVER (PARTITION BY [user_id] ORDER BY  [date]) [Hours-2],
        LAG([day_hours_worked], 3) OVER (PARTITION BY [user_id] ORDER BY  [date]) [Hours-3],
        LAG([day_hours_worked], 4) OVER (PARTITION BY [user_id] ORDER BY  [date]) [Hours-4],
        LAG([day_hours_worked], 5) OVER (PARTITION BY [user_id] ORDER BY  [date]) [Hours-5],
        LAG([day_hours_worked], 6) OVER (PARTITION BY [user_id] ORDER BY  [date]) [Hours-6],
        LAG([day_hours_worked], 7) OVER (PARTITION BY [user_id] ORDER BY  [date]) [Hours-7] 
    from fullData
)
select *
from final
where day_hours_worked is not null
order by [date]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the time spent building this answer, it works really well for a single user like you said! Unfortunately I have more than one user but I appreciate your answer.